# Fixed into right side even though left div is not there - bootstrap

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
<div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-6 left" ng-if="">
           <a ng-click="" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>
       </div>

       <div class="col-md-6 right" ng-if="">
         <a href="" class="btn btn-primary">Reports</a>

   </div>
```

I need to fixed the right div even though the left one is not there due to if condition.Currently it moves to left side when left div hides.I need to avoid that.How can I do that ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add `pull-right` class to the right div - http://www.bootply.com/EPOsUHnRT9

Comment: @MaryMelody I feel you should post it as an answer. You'd receive at least my upvote :-)

Comment: @MaryMelody Thanks a lot it's working perfectly.If you put that as an answer I can accept it.Can you tell me the difference between 'right' and 'pull-right' ?

Comment: @Sampath `right` is not a built-in TWBS's class, `pull-right` *is*.  And it does `float` an element to the right side of its containing block. This solves the problem because columns are floated to the left by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could achive this by adding `pull-right` class to the right div.

**Bootply - [DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/GYITpYg7kg)**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 pull-right" ng-if="">
      <a href="" class="btn btn-primary">Reports</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The `pull-left` and `pull-right` classes are used for float an element to the left or right side:

> Float an element to the left or right with a class.`!important` is
>   included to avoid specificity issues. Classes can also be used as
>   mixins. - by [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-floats)